# python matplotlib imshow() custom tickmarks

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to set custom tick marks on my imshow() output, but haven't found the right combination.

The script below summarizes my attempts. In this script, I'm trying to make the tickmarks at all even numbers on each axis instead of the default (-10,-5,0,5,10)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Generate random histogram
N=25
middle=N/2
hist=np.random.random_sample((N,N))

#Ticks at even numbers, data centered at 0
ticks=np.arange(-middle,middle+2,2)

extent=(-middle,middle,-middle,middle)
plt.imshow(hist, interpolation='nearest', extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()

#
#These are my attempts to set the tick marks
#
#plt.gcf().gca().set_ticks(ticks)

#plt.gca().set_ticks(ticks)

#ax=plt.axes()
#ax.set_ticks(ticks)

plt.show()
```

I'm starting to get the feeling that set_ticks() might not be the way to do it, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks

```
plt.xticks(ticks) # `ticks` is a list here!
```

Edit: as Yann mentions in a comment, you may also be interested in [`plt.yticks()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks)

Result (using `plt.xticks(ticks, fontsize=9)`):
[image]

Comment: or `plt.gca().set_xticks(ticks)`

Comment: +1 - Also, my guess is the OP was looking for both `set_xticks` and `set_yticks`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... not sure how I missed it, thanks!

Comment: @Vorsprung durch Technik is it possible to get the size of the colored tiles form the plot?

Comment: To save people like me from googling: `ticks` above is a list/array rather than an int.

Comment: @JohanDettmar: thanks for adding that, I've updated the answer to include that info.

Comment: What if I want the ticks to be strings?