# Custom tickmarks for python imshow (matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to add custom tickmarks to the following `plt.imshow()` plot (see below):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zmm = np.linspace(0,121,121).reshape(11,11)
plt.imshow(zmm, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.show()
```

[image: figure 1]

I tried to add the custom tickmarks that I need with:

```
xticks = np.linspace(6.5,7.5,6)
yticks = np.linspace(.14,.18,6)

plt.imshow(zmm, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.xticks(xticks)
plt.show()
```

The figure below shows the outcome (trying for both x and yticks conveys even worse results). I could not solve that with this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382664/python-matplotlib-imshow-custom-tickmarks).

[image: figure 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to relabel the ticks (0..10) with the values of `xticks` and `yticks`. It's important to know the difference between a *tick* (the position) and a *label* (the text). See the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).

In your case, the ticks will stay at the same position, while only the labels will change:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

zmm = np.linspace(0,121,121).reshape(11,11)
plt.imshow(zmm, cmap = 'Blues')

nb_ticks = 6

xticks = np.linspace(6.5, 7.5, nb_ticks)
yticks = np.linspace(.14, .18, nb_ticks)

new_xticks = np.linspace(0, 10, nb_ticks)
new_yticks = np.linspace(0, 10, nb_ticks)

plt.xticks(new_xticks, labels=xticks)
plt.yticks(new_yticks, labels=yticks)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if this is not actually an image, you might want to consider using [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html), which takes `x` and `y` values, which are used to determine the ticks. `imshow` uses ticks corresponding to the indices in the array (which `pcolormesh` also does if you don't pass the x and y points). To make your code work, I changed the number of points in `xticks` and `yticks` since there needs to be a one-to-one correspondence for the number of ticks and the rows/columns (depending on x or y).

Also, note that `pcolormesh` doesn't default to square plots like `imshow`, hence the added line to make it square.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xticks = np.linspace(6.5, 7.5, 11)
yticks = np.linspace(0.14, 0.18, 11)

zmm = np.linspace(0, 121, 121).reshape(11, 11)
plt.pcolormesh(xticks, yticks, zmm, cmap='Blues')
plt.gca().set_box_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You'll also note that `pcolormesh` places the origin in the bottom left (like a typical graph) rather than in the top left, which `imshow` does.